# VueJS lifecycle order when combined with router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, lifecycle

I need to run an async initialize method when my app starts. so I did it inside `beforeCreate` of `App.vue` as below.

`app.vue`:

```
export default {
  ...
  beforeCreate () {
    console.log('before create app.vue')
  }
}
```

Also, I need to check a condition before entering any route, so I did it inside `beforeEach` of `router`.

`main.js`:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (condition) {
    console.log('router before each')
  }
})
```

The problem is I need to check the condition after my initialization is done, but, when I launch my app, the condition is checked before the initialization and my output is:

> router before each

> before create app.vue

What am I missing? and how can I fix this?

Comment: Without seeing the full code, I'd guess the navigation is running before `app.vue` is being rendered and, as that's the order it *has* to occur in, there is no way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how I solved it in vue3 but you can use a similar approach... basically don't mount the app until the initialization is completed. In my case the `authCheck` in the initialization function you mention [full source](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ionic-vue3-myapp-login-demo/blob/master/src/main.ts)

```
import useFirebaseAuth from "./hooks/firebase-auth";

const { authCheck  } = useFirebaseAuth();

const app = createApp(App).use(IonicVue);

authCheck()
  .then(() => {
    app.use(router);
    return router.isReady();
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.mount("#app");
  });
```

Comment: I have redesigned my app flow and that fixed the problem. but I checked your answer too and it worked just fine. I liked the idea though and I think this is the (only) solution to my question so I check it as accepted answer. thank you btw

Comment: this is a very good answer, this enforces a certain lifecycle flow which can be very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Yap that is how it suppose to be, the navigation guard is always triggered whenever there is a navigation, meaning it gets executed once it receives your navigation, which is before your component gets created. You can execute anything within your main.js file i don't fully understand what you want to achieve but you can utilize any of the Vue Js lifecycle hooks(https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) to get what you want or the navigation guards(https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) beforeRouteEnter, beforeRouteLeave and beforeRouteUpdate

They all execute at different times, hope this helps